# Mis JTextField no se ven cuando ejecuto mi programa Java

Tags: java, java-swing, macos, jtextfield

mi problema es que cuando ejecuto mi programa, los cuadros de texto no están, pero cuando redimensiono el "frame", aparecen los cuadros de texto.
Sin embargo, aveces ejecuto el código y sí aparecen de primera sin tener que redimensionar el "frame", es muy confuso ya que aveces los pinta de primera y aveces (la mayoría de estas) no los pinta hasta que redimensiono.
Cuando aparecen, el programa funciona bien.

Trabajo en Mac con Catalina.

P.D.: He intentado con paintComponent y sin este, con los métodos updateUI() y repaint().

Aquí dejo el código:

```
package interfaces_graficas;

//import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Eventos6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        MiFrame4 Marco1 = new MiFrame4();
        Marco1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    }

}

class MiFrame4 extends JFrame{
    
    static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
    
    public MiFrame4 (){
        
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(10, 20, 900, 900);
        LaminaFoco miLamina = new LaminaFoco();
        add(miLamina);
    
    }
    
}

class LaminaFoco extends JPanel{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 45L;
    JTextField Cuadro1, Cuadro2;
    
    public LaminaFoco() {
        
        setLayout(null);
        Cuadro1 = new JTextField();
        Cuadro2 = new JTextField();
        Cuadro1.setBounds(120, 10, 120, 20);
        Cuadro2.setBounds(120, 50, 120, 20);
        Cuadro1.setVisible(true);
        Cuadro2.setVisible(true);
        add(Cuadro1);
        add(Cuadro2);
        Foco miFoco = new Foco("Cuadro 1");
        Cuadro1.addFocusListener(miFoco);
        Foco miFoco2 = new Foco("Cuadro 2");
        Cuadro2.addFocusListener(miFoco2);
        
    }
    
    /*public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        repaint(); // updateUI();
    }*/
    
    private class Foco implements FocusListener{
        
        String nombre;
        
        public Foco(String nombre) {
            
            this.nombre = nombre;
        
        }

        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            
            System.out.println(nombre + " ha ganado el foco");
            
        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            
            System.out.println(nombre + " ha perdido el foco");
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque parezca una tontería la solución está en poner el setvisible (true) al final del método constructor public, hay que recordar que el código va de arriba a abajo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no imaginé que eso influyera.